# Heroku and RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubymine

Has anyone managed to integrate Heroku with RubyMine? I have Heroku installed and integrated with Git (which **is** integrated with RubyMine) but I see no way to push to Heroku without dropping to the Terminal.

Comment: If RubyMine allows you to perform 'git push' to an arbitrary branch, just push to whatever you've named your Heroku branch.  Can you paste your `.git/config` file here?

Comment: `
[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = git@github.com:aboutimage/sample_app.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "heroku"]
 url = git@heroku.com:sharp-sunset-177.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
`

@dorkitude #------>Sorry for the messy code, StackOverflow comments doesn't allow for carriage return, so the lines are all mushed together

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special to use Rubymine with Heroku, Heroku is just another git remote location.

From Version Control > Git > Push Changes

there's a 'Remote' drop down, set that to your Heroku remote and it should deploy to Heroku

Comment: I agree with John. Also make sure that the master branch is checked because that is the only branch Heroku is looking for.

Comment: Thanks, John. I found the setting you are talking about, but it appears I need to create the remote repository first. My repository at Heroku is already set up (i.e. if I type 'git push heroku' or 'git push heroku master' the files will upload just fine), but the remote currently listed in the "Remote" drop down is just the Git repository and I have no clue how to create a new one properly.

Comment: To be more clear (it's 2:30am, I'm not sure clarity is something I'm full of at the moment.... ) I found the setting you are talking about, but the only option that shows up in "Remote" is "origin". When I select the dropdown, I see origin(git@github:myusername/myproject). So I'm guessing I have to create a separate remote for Heroku? It's already setup via command line ('git push heroku master' works just fine).

Comment: I would have thought rubymine would have read the gitconfig for the project. if you go to your project in terminal and type git remote -v it will list origin and heroku. When you first create your heroku project via heroku create it will add the heroku remote origin for you. I would have thought rubymine would know about this - i don't recall doing anything special for my projects to get heroku to show up.

Comment: yep, you are correct. I have 4... a fetch/push pair for origin and another fetch-push pair for origin... however, only origin shows up in the "remote" dropdown...

Comment: In any case, John, I think you've pushed me enough in the right direction and helped refine the question, which is now essentially, "How do I get the Heroku remote to show up in the Remote dropdown in RubyMine" (I think). I've posted a question to that effect in the RM forums...

Comment: hehe... I said fetch/push pair for "origin" twice, when of course I meant one pair for origin and another for heroku... a little bleary-eyed this morning...

Comment: I've just opened numerous projects that I've never opened in RubyMine before and all my Heroku remotes are showing up without me doing anything, Rubymine 3.1.1

Comment: I must have something configured incorrectly, then. Heroku works fine from the command line. Just not from RM.